# Chrome Extension run the process on spesific tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm trying to run some scripts on the spesific tab which is assigned on the page of extension's button clicked.

For example, if I click the button which is on the popup.html, it should only run on this page to the end of the script even if I switch to another tab.

My algorithm is like that:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  //Some other processes
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tabS) {
    //Some other processes
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"some_js.js"});
  });
});
```

I'm using some DOM operations on the page. If I switch to another tab, the process is interrupted, because it listens the current tab. I want to assign an id to the process tab and make this codes work on this tab. How can I do it?

Comment: You could inject a popup in the DOM using a content script. During the `browserAction.onClicked` event, you could grab the current tabId and run `chrome.tabs.executeScript` using this value. This way you wouldn't need to the set a popup in your manifest file.

Comment: It doesn't have just chrome.tabs.executeScript, but it has url redirections, http requests, some other executeScript codes in the if else statements, etc. Also I'm inserting a <div> to the page.

Comment: You're not passing the tabId argument to `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. When it is set to null, the script will be executed in the active tab. You need to grab a specific tabId value and pass it to `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. That's why I told you to use `browserAction.onClicked`. This way, the `script.js` will be injected in a tab that the user clicked on you popup's button.

Comment: That's true. Please submit an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a button element in `popup.html`. Then add this code to `popup.js`:

```js
function handleClick (e) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,
        { code: `setInterval(function () { console.log('This event is running only at the tab with domain: ${tabs[0].url} after 1000ms') }, 1000)` })
  })
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const button = document.getElementById('popup-button')
  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
});
```

When you click the button, that code will be executed only in that specific tab. You'll be able to see that message in the developer console.

The code can also be another JS file that you have in your extension. Just like you did it in your question.

*Obs: `chrome.tabs.query` is not really necessary here as if you execute `chrome.tabs.executeScript` passing null as parameter, it already gets the active tab in the current window. I also added the tabs permission in order to get the `tabs[0].url` attribute. Anyway, this way you have more control of what tab you're manipulating as you get their tabId and url attributes.*